# How to get keys of an associative array as an array

Tags: d

(This is a common D question.)

Say I have a D associative array: `string[int] aarr = [ 3 : "three", 5 : "five", 9 : "nine" ];`
- Is there an easy way to get *aarr*'s keys as an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.keys` Returns dynamic array, the elements of which are the keys in the associative array.

See **Properties** section of following link

[Associative Arrays - D Programming Language](http://dlang.org/hash-map.html)

Comment: The idea was to ask and answer the question that comes up quite often both on IRC and the newsgroups. :) Anyway, I will instead accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an attribute `.keys` of every associative array in D which will give you an array which contains keys.

So, `writeln(aarr.keys);` will print `[3, 5, 9]`.

Similarly, `.values` property will give you a dynamic array which contains only values.
`writeln(aarr.values);` will print `["three", "five", "nine"]`.